# Disabling MySQL Strict Mode

Tags: mysql, sql

I am scanning 5000 csv files into a database. Regrettably the files have '', for 0. Thus when ever I run my script it crashes. I heard that this error is possible to avoid by simply disabling strict mode.  So I attempted to disable strict mode to allow me to read in an empty string as a 0 for my numeric fields. However the error persisted.

So does disabling strict mode allow '' to be read into a int field? (the '' is two qoutes i.e. empty string)

If so why did setting

```
sql_mode=''
```

in the my.ini config file does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess you import the CSV file using `LOAD DATA INFILE` command. Before you execute this command, type:

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

More information about various SQL modes can be found in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html).

Comment: Yes you are correct. This works perfectly. I am a little perplexed as to why the setting did not hold, but calling this right before the LOAD DATA command worked. Thanks.

Comment: link is dead. [Click here for documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting) and details of **Server SQL Modes**

Comment: this completely removes sql mode options!

Comment: Global setting can be done by `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=""`

Comment: This does more than just disable strict mode, it removes all configured modes. The default value of `sql_mode` in MySQL 8.0 is `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` according to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-sql-modes.html). To disable strict mode but keep the rest as default, just remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from the line above.

Answer (score 2):

I need do it this, and work correctly:

1. To disable strict SQL mode, SSH in to your server as root
2. Create this file: */etc/mysql/conf.d/disable_strict_mode.cnf*
3. Open the file and enter these two lines:

   [mysqld]
   sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
4. Restart MySQL with this command: *sudo service mysql restart*

Comment: Confirming this solution works on Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify you [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) Statement to correct the values.  Something along these lines should work.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filepath.csv'
INTO TABLE MyTable(Column1,@Col2,@Col3)
SET Column2=CASE WHEN @Col2 = '' THEN 0 ELSE @Col2 END
,Column3=CASE WHEN @Col3 = '' THEN 0 ELSE @Col3 END;
```

This query imports the value as is into column1, and the fixes the values for columns 2 and 3. Using this, you don't have to disable strict mode, and you are actually in control of what data goes into your database, are are able to fix it in a reliable way.  You can also use this feature to change date formats, or import hex encoded blob values. Very useful feature.

Comment: Nice solution. I didn't know it is possible to process the data flow at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this in an answer as I am yet to have the rep to comment on your follow up question about the settings not "holding". It has been my experience with MySQL that the settings in the configuration file are only read on starting the server so that you would have to restart the server for new settings to take effect.

The server is the daemon that the command-line client communicates with when you run commands so that restarting the command line client does not actually restart the server itself.

A more elaborate explanation is provided in this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/79051.