# A mysql error in my.ini

Tags: mysql

Ok so I have

```
sql_mode=""
```

I don't know how to use this to disable Strict SQL Mode in Mysql
Please may someone kindly help me out
Many thanks.

Comment: [See this](https://support.kayako.com/article/472-how-do-i-disable-mysql-strict-mode-on-the-server) and [This one](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-disable-strict-mode-in-mysql-5-7.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling MySQL Strict Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040207/disabling-mysql-strict-mode)

Answer (score 0):

SSH into your server and edit `/etc/my.cnf`

Note: You should have root access to this server.

Once you ssh into the server, type:

```
sudo nano /etc/usr.cnf
```

Add the following line:

```
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save, then enter, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Alternatively, if you are using a VPS host, you can use phpMyAdmin in WHM to edit sql mode under variables to

```
NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.
```