# Field 'cover' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, typo3

Im using the `tx_sfbooks` extension to add Books to my website.

When I add a new record I get the following error :

```
2: SQL error: 'Field 'cover' doesn't have a default value' (tx_sfbooks_domain_model_book:NEW60807a6c5dce2359862008)
```

I tried to add a default value for the field `cover` in the table `tx_sfbooks_domain_model_book` but I get an error on mysql because this field is `BLOB` type.

I tried also the disable strict SQL mode : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45059826/11541354

but always the same error.

this is the schema :

```
#
# Table structure for table 'tx_sfbooks_domain_model_book'
#
CREATE TABLE tx_sfbooks_domain_model_book
(
    number       tinytext                     NOT NULL,
    title        tinytext                     NOT NULL,
    path_segment varchar(2048),
    subtitle     tinytext                     NOT NULL,
    author       tinytext                     NOT NULL,
    isbn         tinytext                     NOT NULL,
    series       int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    category     int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    description  text                         NOT NULL,
    extras       blob                         NOT NULL,
    cover        blob                         NOT NULL,
    cover_large  blob                         NOT NULL,
    sample_pdf   blob                         NOT NULL,
    year         varchar(4)       DEFAULT ''  NOT NULL,
    location1    int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    location2    int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    location3    int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);
```

Im using MySQL 8.0.23

Comment: Look at the schema for this table! Or show it to us if is not obvious when you look

Comment: If there is no default value set in the schema, you have to pass a value in the INSERT for that column

Comment: Since `cover` is just a file reference (relation) field https://github.com/evoWeb/sf_books/blob/develop/Configuration/TCA/tx_sfbooks_domain_model_book.php#L326 , it should actually be an integer column. Without MySQL `strict_mode` the integer was possible to be saved into `BLOB`. IMHO that is an error in the extension's TCA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by turn off Mysql `strict mode`, by this command:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
```

To verify, run this command :

```
 mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;"
```

And you should see:

```
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| sql_mode      | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+------------------------+
```